# How does one know if their master/slave peripheral implementing a standard bus is doing the job correctly?

Tags: digital-logic, fpga, bus

There are many standard buses like Avalon-MM, Avalon-ST, Wishbone, AMBA-AXI, AMBA-AHB, AMBA_APB e.t.c. These standard buses have been designed to have a non trivial structure so they can be used in a lot of different applications. This raises the question, how does one verify that their implementation of the master or slave peripheral that is using one of these buses is correct?

Comment: Per previous comment, you can find resources (already proven), allowing the tests to be simplified. www.osvvm.org is one source of verification IP for AXI at least, as one of the facilities it offers.

Answer (score 3):

Same as every design: testing, testing, and more testing. Importantly, this must be done to a plan, rather than just using it and hoping you've covered all the cases. This could be directed tests, soak tests, formal, etc. The protocols can be very complex, so there's a good chance you won't be using all the features and signals of a given protocol. This allows you to limit your verification space.

For the most common protocols, there are pieces of verification IP (VIP) designed to do exactly what you're asking, including plans, coverage points etc. For example, Synopsys (no affiliation) offer [VIP](https://www.synopsys.com/verification/verification-ip/amba.html) for all the AMBA protocols. Of course, you have to trust that *they've* implemented it correctly, but you can be sure they've done a better job than you are likely to have done by yourself.

Comment: That IP is probably going to be quite expensive I must say.

Comment: Yes, but a lot cheaper (probably) than a respin or recall of a broken design! This was just an example as a quick search, there will be cheaper/free others for sure.